# How to get values from a "cell" of a "groupby" object?

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

Assume that I have the following data frame:

```
     A    B  C   D
0  foo  one  1  10
1  bar  one  2  20
2  foo  two  3  30
3  bar  one  4  40
4  foo  two  5  50
5  bar  two  6  60
6  foo  one  7  70
7  foo  two  8  80
```

Now I can group by the first column: `grouped = df.groupby('A')`. As a result I get the following `DataFrameGroupBy` object:

```
     A            B                 C              D
0  foo  [one,two,two,one,two]  [1,3,5,7,8]  [10,30,50,70,80]
1  bar  [one,one,two]          [2,4,6]      [20,40,60]
```

Now I would like to access the values from a particular cell. How can I do it? For example I want to get the values from the column 'D' and the row where `'A'=='foo'` (the first row). In other words I want to get `[10,30,50,70,80]`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you thinking of something like this?

```
>>> df
     A    B  C   D
0  foo  one  1  10
1  bar  one  2  20
2  foo  two  3  30
3  bar  one  4  40
4  foo  two  5  50
5  bar  two  6  60
6  foo  one  7  70
7  foo  two  8  80
>>> df.groupby("A").get_group("foo")["D"]
0    10
2    30
4    50
6    70
7    80
Name: D
>>> df.groupby("A").get_group("foo")["D"].tolist()
[10, 30, 50, 70, 80]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by this statement:

```
>>> df.groupby("A").get_group("foo")["D"]
0    10
2    30
4    50
6    70
7    80
Name: D
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be an old question, but here is my solution to-go:

```
_b, _c, _d, _s = [], [], [], []

group_df = df.groupby("A")

for s in dict(list(group_df)).keys():

    b_ = group_df.get_group(s)['B'].tolist()
    c_ = group_df.get_group(s)['C'].tolist()
    d_ = group_df.get_group(s)['D'].tolist()    
    _s.append(s)
    _b.append(b_)
    _c.append(c_)
    _d.append(d_)
        
regrouped_df = (
    pd.DataFrame(zip(_s, _b, _c, _d))
    .rename(columns={0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C", 3: "D"})
)

>> regrouped_df 
         A                          B                C                     D
    0  bar            [one, one, two]        [2, 4, 6]          [20, 40, 60]
    1  foo  [one, two, two, one, two]  [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]  [10, 30, 50, 70, 80]
```