# Parsing the data from excel file and send calendar invite using python script

Tags: python

I have a input excel file with the below data :

```
Server Name Event   Deploy Dist Type    Engineer    CR Number   Env Deployment Status   Date (IT)   Start (IT)  End (IT)    Primary Application
A   X   X   X   X   X   X   1/11/2019   8:30    12:30   X
B   X   X   X   X   X   X   1/11/2019   8:30    12:30   X
C   X   X   X   X   X   X   1/13/2019   8:30    12:30   X
D   X   X   X   X   X   X   1/13/2019   8:30    15:30   X
```

I need to send calendar invite as below (Groupby with dates)

1.Date, start time (smaller value in column [start{IT]]), End time (Greater value in column (End (IT)))

Below should print in calendar invite body

```
Server Name Event   Deploy Dist Type    Engineer    CR Number   Env Deployment Status   Date (IT)   Start (IT)  End (IT)    Primary Application
A   X   X   X   X   X   X   1/11/2019   8:30    12:30   X
B   X   X   X   X   X   X   1/11/2019   8:30    12:30   X
```

2.Same as 1

```
Server Name Event   Deploy Dist Type    Engineer    CR Number   Env Deployment Status   Date (IT)   Start (IT)  End (IT)    Primary Application
C   X   X   X   X   X   X   1/13/2019   8:30    12:30   X
D   X   X   X   X   X   X   1/13/2019   8:30    15:30   X
```

I got the code to send calendar invite but not sure how to parse the inputs like the above and send multiple invites based on date in input file

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import encoders
from tabulate import tabulate
import os, datetime
import csv
import pandas

#path_to_file = "C:\Users\kj\Desktop\Jan\sample.csv"
path_to_file = "C:/Users/kj/Desktop/Jan/sample_upd.csv"
output_to_file= "C:/Users/kj/Desktop/Jan/output.csv"
df = pandas.read_csv(path_to_file)
grouped = df.groupby('Date (IT)')
text = """
"""

html = """
<html><body><p></p>
<p></p>
{table}
<p></p>
<p></p>
</body></html>
"""
for name, group in grouped:
    dates_grp = name
    group.to_csv(output_to_file)

    CRLF = "\r\n"
    attendees = ["test@test.com"]
    organizer = "ORGANIZER;CN=organiser:mailto:test@test.com"
    fro = "test@test.com <test@test.com>"

    ddtstart = datetime.datetime.now()
    dtoff = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    dur = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
    ddtstart = ddtstart + dtoff
    dtend = ddtstart + dur
    dtstamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
    dtstart = ddtstart.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
    dtend = dtend.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")

    description = "DESCRIPTION: OS PATCHING" + CRLF
    attendee = ""
    for att in attendees:
        attendee += "ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-    PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE" + CRLF + " ;CN=" + att + ";X-NUM-GUESTS=0:" + CRLF + " mailto:" + att + CRLF
    ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR" + CRLF + "PRODID:pyICSParser" + CRLF + "VERSION:2.0" + CRLF + "CALSCALE:GREGORIAN" + CRLF
    ical += "METHOD:REQUEST" + CRLF + "BEGIN:VEVENT" + CRLF + "DTSTART:" + dtstart + CRLF + "DTEND:" + dtend + CRLF + "DTSTAMP:" + dtstamp + CRLF + organizer + CRLF
    ical += "UID:FIXMEUID" + dtstamp + CRLF
    ical += attendee + "CREATED:" + dtstamp + CRLF + description + "LAST-MODIFIED:" + dtstamp + CRLF + "LOCATION:" + CRLF + "SEQUENCE:0" + CRLF + "STATUS:CONFIRMED" + CRLF
    ical += "SUMMARY:test " + ddtstart.strftime(
        "%Y%m%d @ %H:%M") + CRLF + "TRANSP:OPAQUE" + CRLF + "END:VEVENT" + CRLF + "END:VCALENDAR" + CRLF

    with open(output_to_file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        eml_body = list(reader)
    text = text.format(table=tabulate(eml_body, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
    html = html.format(table=tabulate(eml_body, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))
    eml_body_bin = "This is the email body in binary - two steps"
    msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
    msg['Reply-To'] = fro
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = "pyICSParser invite" + dtstart
    msg['From'] = fro
    msg['To'] = ",".join(attendees)

    #part_email = MIMEText(eml_body, "html")
    part_cal = MIMEText(ical, 'calendar;method=REQUEST')

    #msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart("alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html, 'html')])
    msg.attach(msgAlternative)

    ical_atch = MIMEBase('application/ics', ' ;name="%s"' % ("invite.ics"))
    ical_atch.set_payload(ical)
    encoders.encode_base64(ical_atch)
    ical_atch.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % ("invite.ics"))

    eml_atch = MIMEBase('text/plain', ' ')
    # encoders.encode_base64(eml_atch)
    encoders.encode_7or8bit(eml_atch)
    eml_atch.add_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', "")

    #msgAlternative.attach(part_email)
    msgAlternative.attach(part_cal)

    mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('test.test.com')
    # mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('MSGEXSV2D3906',25)
    # mailServer = smtplib.SMTP(s)
    mailServer.ehlo()
    # mailServer.starttls()
    mailServer.ehlo()
    # mailServer.login(login, password)
    mailServer.sendmail(fro, attendees, msg.as_string())
    mailServer.close()
    break
```

Comment: Updated the code, now i am able to send invite using grouped data.  But need help in parsing date and time from the output of groupy. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Do you think of this [how-to-get-values-from-a-cell-of-a-groupby-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002085/how-to-get-values-from-a-cell-of-a-groupby-object)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to complete the script....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: Parsing the data from excel file and send calendar invite

You have **to modularize** into the following, using `function` or `class`:

1. Module **Data**

   - Group the Excel Data
   - Parse Data Row by Row
2. Module **ICAL**

   - Create a `ICAL` Record from Excel Row Data
3. Module **Mail**

   - Prepare Mail using `ICAL` Record
   - Send Mail

> Implementation - 1. Module **Data**

1. [Reading an Excel file using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36590692/7414759)

   ```
   import pandas
   df = pandas.read_excel(open('your_xls_xlsx_filename','rb'), sheetname='Sheet 1')
   ```
2. [Loop over grouped Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49565811/7414759)

   ```
   grouped = df.groupby('Date (IT)')

   for name, group in grouped:
       ...
   ```

Comment: I am stuck at "Getting the inputs from excel file and further process"

Comment: Updated the code, now i am able to send invite using grouped data. But need help in parsing date and time from the output of groupy. Any suggestion please?